# How to add TailwindCSS to Docker container?

Tags: docker, pip, dockerfile, tailwind-css, permission-denied

I'm trying to add TailwindCSS to Docker container but after running tailwindcss command in bash, it just says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tailwindcss", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytailwindcss/__main__.py", line 9, in main
    completed_process = pytailwindcss.run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytailwindcss/__init__.py", line 45, in run
    install(version, bin_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytailwindcss/__init__.py", line 69, in install
    return install_binary(version, ensure_is_pathlib_path(bin_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytailwindcss/installation.py", line 25, in install_binary
    os.makedirs(bin_path.parent, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytailwindcss/bin
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.10-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

ARG FLASK_APP=project.app
ENV FLASK_APP=${FLASK_APP}

ARG FLASK_RUN_PORT=5001
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=${FLASK_RUN_PORT}

CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0 # --port=${FLASK_RUN_PORT} --app=${FLASK_APP}

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
RUN pip --disable-pip-version-check install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp

COPY . .

RUN pip --disable-pip-version-check install -v -e .

ARG CI_COMMIT_SHA
ENV CI_COMMIT_SHA=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}

RUN echo "BUILD_DATE=$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')" >> /app/.env

ARG USERNAME=vscode
RUN test ! -z "${USERNAME}" && mkdir -p /home/${USERNAME}/.vscode-server/extensions && \
    chown -R $USERNAME /home/$USERNAME/.vscode-server
```

EDIT:
Requirements.txt

importlib-metadata
flask
python-dotenv
flask-login
passlib
flask-mongoengine
python-dateutil
pytailwindcss
pre-commit
sentry-sdk[flask]
sentry-sdk[pymongo]

**Any idea how to make TailwindCSS work in a Docker container?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems you run `/usr/local/bin/tailwindcss` but it's not in the part of `Dockerfile` that you show, Please show the full text of your `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @phd Added missing info that you requested

Comment: Tnx, that's better. But I still do not understand how do run `/usr/local/bin/tailwindcss` . You install `pytailwindcss` but by itself it installs the script but doesn't run it. Perhaps you run it manually? Whith waht command line?

Comment: I just type tailwindcss to bash terminal to test it that it's installed correctly. (inside the docker container). But it just says the error that I posted here. For example, passlib works just fine when I added it to the requirements.txt. When I rebuilt the container, it got installed correctly and I could use it. Didn't happen with tailwind